# GitHub project board not copying with repo; is this possible?

Tags: github, kanban

I've set up a public [GH project board](https://github.com/jakeheft/mod_1_pre-work/projects/1) that I wanted to share with some people, but when they fork it, only the code transfers over and their project tab remains empty. How can I share this so people can use it? I tried setting it up as a template but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I never seen the notion of "fork" for a project board. Only link.

See "[Linking a repository to a project board](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-repository-to-a-project-board)"

> Anyone with write permissions to a project board can link repositories owned by that organization or user account to the project board.

> You can link up to twenty-five repositories to your organization or user-owned project board.
> Linking repositories makes it easier to add issues and pull requests from those repositories to your project board using Add cards or from the issue or pull requests sidebar

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe GH can do this. Gitlab can.